# hardhat deployment on Sepolia

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat, etherscan

I try many times to deploy my contract by running :

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia` and all I get is an error message saying:

> Error HH100: Network sepolia doesn't exist For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH100 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces any help ?

I really don't know what is the issue? Any one can help please? png file is attached. All things seem to be good:

- sepolia testnet balance is available for paying gas
- url from Quicknode is doublechecked
- .env file is added
- compiled is done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Vno.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same error a few days back. This was how I resolved it:

1. Take a backup of your project files.
2. Initialize a new project using npm init or yarn init.
3. Install hardhat dependency.
4. Creat a new hardhat project with an empty configuration.
5. Copy paste all the files again to new project and it will start work again

Answer (score 0):

i think you're missing a crucial property, `chainId`, which sepolia testnet is [11155111](https://chainlist.org/chain/11155111) so you should modify hardhat.config.js as follow:

```js
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      chainId: 11155111,
      url: QUICKNODE_HTTP_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
};
```